# Regular Expression for numeric csv data

Tags: jquery, regex, csv

I have data like: 
1,2,3,4,5

numeric data which can be csv. I am trying /[0-9]+(,[0-9])*/ but its not working.

Any suggestion please.. it will be of great help.

Comment: Have you tried web resources like https://regex101.com/ or  http://www.regextester.com/ ? This can help with both learning and debugging regular expressions.

Comment: Why no `string.split(",")`?

Comment: First things first: what is the question? You are trying `/[0-9]+(,[0-9])*/`: where? what is it supposed to do? why not a CSV parser?

Comment: I have an input box that can accept numeric data in csv format. Better to give user error if data is not in correct format.

Comment: var Reg = /d+/;
this worked for me. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take only the numbers:
[0-9]
If you want to take the number and the comma:
,?[0-9]
And, if you want to take all the characters in a string:
[0-9],+([0-9],?)*

Comment: Thx.. actually this worked for me function validateNumericCSV($data) {
    var Reg = /d+/;
    return Reg.test($data);
}